# Rendering string to mail preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I have a string, which is a mail content, and I want to see that content in Rails' preview function available at `/rails/mailers`. I do not have a particular mailer class for that mail (I call it from a controller).

Is there a way to send a string to Rails' mail previewer?

Comment: You could make a generic mailer class and have the content as a `yield`, then use that as the body, presumably.